# Need help to simplify query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query which need to simplify and still give the same result but faster , This is the **Result** query

```sql
SELECT Table2.PoNumber
     , Nz([MaterialCode],"None") AS MatCode
     , Nz([Material],"None") AS Mat
     , Nz([MaterialCons],"None") AS MatCons
     , Nz([MasterCode],"None") AS MastCode
     , Nz([Master],"None") AS Masterr
     , Nz([MasterCons],"None") AS MasterrCons
     , Nz([StretchCode],"None") AS StrCode
     , Nz([Stretch],"None") AS Str
     , Nz([StretchCons],"None") AS StrCons
     , Nz([PackCode],"None") AS PacCode
     , Nz([Pack],"None") AS Package
     , Nz([PackCons],"None") AS PacCons
     , Nz([MasterCons]/[MaterialCons],0) AS MasterPercent
FROM (((Table2 LEFT JOIN Sub1 ON Table2.PoNumber = Sub1.Po) 
LEFT JOIN Sub2 ON Table2.PoNumber = Sub2.Po) 
LEFT JOIN Sub3 ON Table2.PoNumber = Sub3.Po) 
LEFT JOIN Sub4 ON Table2.PoNumber = Sub4.Po;
```

This query depend on 4 Sub queries:

**Sub1**

```sql
SELECT Table1.Code AS MaterialCode
     , Table1.Item AS Material
     , Table1.Cons AS MaterialCons
     , Table1.Po
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Type)="Material"))
GROUP BY Table1.Code
       , Table1.Item
       , Table1.Cons
       , Table1.Po;
```

**Sub2**

```sql
SELECT Table1.Code AS MasterCode
     , Table1.Item AS Master
     , Table1.Cons AS MasterCons
     , Table1.Po
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Type)="MasterPatch"))
GROUP BY Table1.Code
       , Table1.Item
       , Table1.Cons
       , Table1.Po;
```

**Sub3**

```sql
SELECT Table1.Code AS StretchCode
     , Table1.Item AS Stretch
     , Table1.Cons AS StretchCons
     , Table1.Po
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Type)="Stretch"))
GROUP BY Table1.Code
       , Table1.Item
       , Table1.Cons
       , Table1.Po;
```

**Sub4**

```sql
SELECT Table1.Code AS PackCode
     , Table1.Item AS Pack
     , Table1.Cons AS PackCons
     , Table1.Po
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Type)="Package"))
GROUP BY Table1.Code
       , Table1.Item
       , Table1.Cons
       , Table1.Po;
```

I need to cancel those 4 sub queries and still get the same result.
Note: the main db became UGLY because of so many queries depend on the same way of joining. Basically depend on one or two tables but with multiple criteria. So I need the way to be more efficient.

Thanks.

Comment: In SQL Server, I'd use PIVOT for that. It appears that Access [has something similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/transform-statement-microsoft-access-sql). Unfortunately, I don't have experience with Access' pivot feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you intend to develop a wide format of your data, consider conditional formatting with `LEFT JOIN` of the two tables. However, only one value per group will be reshaped wide. Therefore, using `MAX` below will pick the maximum alphabetically ordered value if string or maximum number value if number for *Code*, *Item*, and *Cons* fields. No data is lost if there are only one *Code*, *Item*, *Cons* per *Type* grouping.

Also, given you run a division on *Cons* columns, these are assumed to be number fields and hence are not wrapped in `NZ` and `'None'` to return string column. If *Cons* are numbers, consider adjusting aggregation from `MAX` to `SUM` or `AVG` as needed. Finally, division by zero is avoided.

```sql
SELECT t2.PoNumber
     , Nz(MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Material', t1.Code, NULL)), 'None') AS MatCode
     , Nz(MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Material', t1.Item, NULL)), 'None') AS Mat
     , MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Material', t1.Cons, NULL)) AS MatCons

     , Nz(MAX(IIF(t1.Type='MasterPatch', t1.Code, NULL)), 'None') AS MastCode
     , Nz(MAX(IIF(t1.Type='MasterPatch', t1.Item, NULL)), 'None') AS Masterr
     , MAX(IIF(t1.Type='MasterPatch', t1.Cons, NULL)) AS MasterCons

     , Nz(MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Stretch', t1.Code, NULL)), 'None') AS StrCode
     , Nz(MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Stretch', t1.Item, NULL)), 'None') AS Str
     , MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Stretch', t1.Cons, NULL)) AS StrCons

     , Nz(MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Package', t1.Code, NULL)), 'None') AS PacCode
     , Nz(MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Package', t1.Item, NULL)), 'None') AS Package
     , MAX(IIF(t1.Type='Package', t1.Cons, NULL)) AS PacCons

     , Nz(IIF([MatCons] <> 0, [MasterCons] / [MatCons], NULL), 0) AS MasterPercent

FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.PoNumber = t1.Po
GROUP BY t2.PoNumber
```

Alternatively, if there are more than one *Code*, *Item*, and *Cons* per *Type* grouping, avoid aggregation at outer level. Notice use of `DISTINCT` and *Type* added to `SELECT` for `IIF` conditionals in outer level.

```sql
SELECT t2.PoNumber
     , IIF(t1.Type='Material', t1.Code, 'None') AS MatCode
     , IIF(t1.Type='Material', t1.Item, 'None') AS Mat
     , IIF(t1.Type='Material', t1.Cons, NULL) AS MatCons

     , IIF(t1.Type='MasterPatch', t1.Code, 'None') AS MastCode
     , IIF(t1.Type='MasterPatch', t1.Item, 'None') AS Masterr
     , IIF(t1.Type='MasterPatch', t1.Cons, NULL) AS MasterCons

     , IIF(t1.Type='Stretch', t1.Code, 'None') AS StrCode
     , IIF(t1.Type='Stretch', t1.Item, 'None') AS Str
     , IIF(t1.Type='Stretch', t1.Cons, NULL) AS StrCons

     , IIF(t1.Type='Package', t1.Code, 'None') AS PacCode
     , IIF(t1.Type='Package', t1.Item, 'None') AS Package
     , IIF(t1.Type='Package', t1.Cons, NULL) AS PacCons

     , NZ(IIF([MatCons] <> 0, [MasterCons] / [MatCons], NULL), 0) AS MasterPercent

FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Type], [Code], [Item], [Cons], [Po]
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.Type IN ('Material', 'MasterPatch', 'Stretch', 'Package')
) t1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the purpose of group by a sub query. I think your whole query should look like this:

```
SELECT Table2.PoNumber, ...
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.PoNumber = Table1.Po
WHERE Table1.Type IN ("Material", "MasterPatch", "Stretch", "Package");
```

Comment: About the group i can’t disagree but on the other hand I think you missed the point here , The whole idea from sub query is to get one result depend on type not all of types , So In("","","") Won’t work here

Comment: Then you should add the group by Type at the end of suggested query, whould that work?

Comment: I Don’t follow , You can try it and share the result with me

Comment: How can I share a result if I don't know how your data looks like and what you expect as result?

Comment: I forgot , No Attachments here Lol